# AngularJS: How to select element with non-breaking space (&nbsp) in id value

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using `angular.element` to select elements using their IDs.

```
vm.onPreview = function(e){
            $timeout(function () {            
                angular.element(e.$element[0].id).triggerHandler('click');
        }, 0);
    }
```

It works fine except for elements where id contains **non-breaking space (&nbsp)**. These ids are part of dynamically generate templates therefore I cannot change the way they are created.

For id `#form-0-Spec&nbsp;Design-input` I get this error:

`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #form-0-Spec&nbsp;Design-input`.

How can I select elements which has non-breaking space in their ids?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace '&nbsp' with ' '. Like this

Let

```
var Id = form-0-Spec&nbsp;Design-input;// your dynamically create element name.
 var newId = Id.replace("&nbsp;"," ");
```

This `newId` will give you the output as form-0-Spec Design-input. I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks @Monicka . For editing my answer.I just wrote it in my mobile . So this happens. Anyways thanks.

Comment: It does not trigger click event if I replace nbsp; with space.

Comment: Make sure you can able to acces the element using newId . Else can you please try this it may work for you. Just do something like this.                                  
             var el = document.getElementById(newId);
            angular.element(el).triggerHandler('click');